# Getting "contract is missing links for the following libraries" error even after adding as libraries while getting contract factory using ethers.js

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, hardhat

I deployed a contract with an external library using hardhat. Now I am trying to do a write operation on the contract but it is throwing an error: `contract is missing links for the following libraries` even though I am adding it as a library by specifying it in this way:

```
const C1 = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("CONTRACT NAME", {
  libraries: {
    Setter: "LIBRARY ADDRESS",
  },
});
```

Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try:

1. Make sure that the library address you're specifying in the
   **libraries** property is correct. Double-check the address and ensure
   it matches the library contract's address on the blockchain.
2. Check that the library contract has been deployed to the network
   you're deploying your contract to.
3. Try using the **deployed** method instead of the **deploy** method to deploy
   your contract. The **deployed** method checks if the contract has
   already been deployed and, if so, returns a reference to the
   existing contract instance. This can help ensure that the contract
   is correctly linked to the library.

Here's an example:

```js
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');

async function main() {
  const C1 = await ethers.getContractFactory('MyContract', {
    libraries: {
      MyLibrary: '0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890',
    },
  });

  // Check if the contract has already been deployed
  const c1 = await C1.deployed() || await C1.deploy();

  console.log('MyContract deployed to:', c1.address);
}

main();
```

In this example, we use the **deployed** method to check if the contract has already been deployed. If it has, we get a reference to the existing contract instance. If it hasn't, we use the **deploy** method to deploy the contract and link it to the library.

Hopefully, one of these solutions will help resolve the issue.